# Following the Von Neumann definition of ordinal, why $V$ is not a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Closed_unbounded_sets_and_classes)
(section "Von Neumann definition of ordinals"):
"... every set of ordinals has a supremum, the ordinal obtained by taking the union of all the ordinals in the set (this union exists regardless of the set's size, by the axiom of union)".

If this is correct, then why V is not a set? (assuming the Von Neumann definition of V (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe): $V=\bigcup_{\alpha} V_{\alpha}$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has two parts which are really unrelated. Every set of sets has a union, that is the axiom of union. From this follows that every set of ordinals has a supremum, its union.

Then you ask on something which is very much *not* a set of ordinals $\{V_\alpha\mid\alpha\in\rm Ord\}$. Standard arguments show that $V$ is not a set, therefore this collection of sets is not a set either.

Similarly, when you have a regular cardinal, like $\omega_1$, the union of every countable set of countable ordinals is *not* $\omega_1$; or in general the countable union of countable sets is countable. When the collection you're taking union over is not a set, then there is no reason to expect that the resulting union is a set.

Comment: I wonder if instead of $V=\bigcup_{\alpha} V_{\alpha}$ we define $V_{Ord}=\bigcup_{\alpha} V_{\alpha}^{Ord}$ where $V_{\alpha}^{Ord}$ is the ordinal of the same cardinality of $V_{\alpha}$. In this case $V_{Ord}$ is a set, right?

Comment: No. You are taking a union over a proper class. Here's a nice analogy which might be helpful. Consider only the finite cases (i.e. work in $\sf ZFC-Inf+\lnot Inf$, where all the ordinals are just natural numbers). Then you are taking an infinite union over finite ordinals. Is the result likely to be a finite ordinal?

Comment: I want to understand what is wrong in the original argument. Is it then that"... every set of ordinals has a supremum, the ordinal obtained by taking the union of all the ordinals in the set (this union exists regardless of the set's size, by the axiom of union)" is wrong? is it true only for a finite union?.

Comment: Ugh. No. Let me start over. Consider the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ but replace the axiom of infinity by its negation. Now every set is finite. Now you have a proper class (read: an infinite collection) of ordinals, and you take a union of that class. So you are asking whether or not a union of infinitely finite ordinals is a finite ordinal. Is it? Do you expect it to be? Now back in the usual $\sf ZFC$ axioms, we replace "finite" by "set" and "infinite" by "proper class". You are taking a union over a collection which is not a set, why do you expect it to be a set?

Comment: because wikipedia says so? quote: "... every set of ordinals has a supremum, ** bold the ordinal obtained ** by taking the union of all the ordinals in the set (this union exists regardless of the set's size, by the axiom of union)".

Comment: But the collection of all ordinals is not a set. Just like the collection of all finite ordinals is not a finite ordinal, and the collection of all countable ordinals is not a countable ordinal.

Comment: OK, I believe you. Can't you tell me what is wrong in the argument? (it says that the supremum is an ordinal)

Comment: The supremum of a **set** of ordinals is an ordinal, and it is the union of the set of ordinals. Nothing wrong there. The supremum over a *proper class* of ordinals is not an ordinal, and $\{|V_\alpha|\mid\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}\}$ is *not* a set of ordinals, but a proper class of ordinals.

Comment: But is not $Vα^{Ord}$ α∈Ord as defined above, a set of ordinals? (I mean, each one is an ordinal)

Comment: No. It's not a set of ordinals, because $\{V_\alpha\mid\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}\}$ is not a set of sets, it's a proper class of sets (and I really have no idea what $|V\alpha|^{Ord}$ would mean in your notation).

Comment: Ok, I'll try to think about it, but still do not get what it is wrong. I might ask a different but related question tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I really don't know what else to add. The collection of all $V_\alpha$ is not a set, each is provably of a different cardinality then the others, so the map $V_\alpha\mapsto|V_\alpha|$ is injective, and therefore its range is not a set, and therefore its union is not a set. *Really* what's the issue? Where in the five statements in this comments is your confusion?

Comment: Does "the supremum of a set of ordinals" assume that the collection is a set or only that the elements are sets?

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ were a set, then it would be a member of $V$, since all sets are members of $V$, but then it would have as its rank some ordinal, and there would be greater ordinals $\alpha$, hence sets $V_\alpha$ of which $V$ is a subset, and which do not belong to $V$.

Remember that the class of all ordinals is not a set.  If it were a set, then it would be an ordinal, and it would have a successor ordinal, and the ordinals would then go on from there, beyond the extent of how far ordinals go.

Comment: I understand the argument that V cannot be a set. I am asking why it does not contradict the Von Neumann definition. Or at least what is wrong in the quoted text.

Comment: Asaf's answer was more direct, the wrong assumption was that the sets V_alpha were ordinals. I am not sure if you stated that, perhaps you did but I didnt get it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I certainly didn't have in mind that $V_\alpha$ is an ordinal.  Are  you somehow getting that from my answer?

Comment: No, I did! but that was wrong and I am not sure if your answer  was pointing at that or not. Sorry for the confusion.